# Windows Server 2022 RDS Cal with 2019 Session Host not used

Tags: windows-server-2019, rds, windows-server-2022, cal

I have a Windows 2022 Licensing Server with 2019 RDS CALs and 2022 RDS User CALs. I only have Windows 2019 Session Hosts.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license#rds-cal-version-compatibility it should be possible to use 2022 CALs for 2019 Session Hosts, but while the 2019 CALs are overused, the 2022 CALs are not used at all (except for my own session on the licensing server itself).

Is it somehow necessary to mark the 2022 licenses for use with 2019 server? Or do they need to be downgraded somehow to actually be used?